# How can I make the user of my program enter only one comma

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Suppose we created a program to calculate the average of a subject and entered the `test1` point and the `test2` point, and then the average is displayed.

We need two edits to enter the `test1` and `test2`, and one edit to show the average. As we know, that the `test1` or `test2` point, for example, if it is `15,5` it means that the point, if it is decimal, will consist of a comma, meaning it cannot be a decimal number that contains two commas, for example `15,15,1`, as this is not a decimal number.

How can I make the user of my program enter only one comma, that is, how do I prevent him from entering several commas in order for error messages not to appear?

I apologize if my explanation was not clear. What is the code that I can write to make users enter only one comma, and where do I write it? For example, in the edit itself, or in the properties `OnChange` or `OnKeyPress`, or where exactly?

I tried writing this code in the `OnChange` event:

```
if not ( Key in ['0'..'9'] + [',',#8] ) then Key := #0;
```

to make the user write only the numbers and the comma, and let `#8` to erase what was written.

But despite this, he can enter a number that contains more than one comma, which means that he can still write, for example, `15,5,1` or `9,9,9`, although I want him to write only a valid decimal with one comma, because a decimal number can't contain more than one comma.

I think that the solution is, for example, to put the condition '*'*1, but I don't know how to employ the idea. I mean, the comma is multiplied once.

Or, what do you think?

Comment: Use a ``TMaskEdit``

Comment: Be aware that "_enter_" also means pasting clipboard content (having multiple commas) at once instead of typing text key by key.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [`TryStrToFloat()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToFloat) in the `SysUtils` unit to validate the user's input at the time you are actually ready to perform the calculation.  That will allow you to do your own error handling, etc.

For example:

```
uses
  ..., SysUtils;

procedure TMyForm.GetAverageButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  point1, point2: Double;
begin
  if not TryStrToFloat(Edit1.Text, point1) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Point1 is not valid');
    Edit1.SetFocus;
    Exit;
  end;

  if not TryStrToFloat(Edit2.Text, point2) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Point2 is not valid');
    Edit2.SetFocus;
    Exit;
  end;

  Edit3.Text := FloatToStr((point1 + point2) / 2.0);
end;
```

Don't bother wasting your time/effort validating every individual key press - especially since you are not fully validating the input anyway, ie you are not preventing the user from entering more than 1 comma, etc.

Comment: I wrote as you did, but look, it is still possible to insert more than one comma: - https://j.top4top.io/p_2656nkco41.png -. I want to write a code to type the comma from the keyboard only once

Comment: "*it is still possible to insert more than one comma*" - of course it is, because this approach is not blocking the user from entering whatever they want, but that is OK because `TryStrToFloat()` will return `False` if they do enter invalid input. And then you can warn the user however you want to fix their mistake.

Comment: "*I want to write a code to type the comma from the keyboard only once*" - you really SHOULD NOT try to block input WHILE it is still being entered. That is just unnecessary work on your part. But, if you absolutely need to, then you will have to do something like `if (Key = ',') and (Pos(',', Edit1.Text) <> 0) then Key := #0;`

Comment: I really thank you my friend, yes I was in dire need of this, it worked for me, thank you proooo < =) >

Comment: Remy, TNumberBox and plenty of other number editor components blocks it, and it's fine. Could be a better UX to do inplace validation, it depends on context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pos` function to check if a comma already exists:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (Key = '.') and ('.' <> DecimalSeparator) then
    Key := DecimalSeparator;
  if not (Key in ['0'..'9', DecimalSeparator, #8]) then
  begin
    Key := #0;
    Beep;
    Exit;
  end;
  if (Key = DecimalSeparator)
    and (Pos(DecimalSeparator, TEdit(Sender).Text) > 0) then
  begin
    Key := #0;
    Beep;
  end;
end;
```

Aditionally, it accepts dot char, if the user uses number pad, and converts it to decimal separator if needed.

Comment: thank you so much pro, Thank you for your effort and time, I really appreciate this < =) >

Comment: Hello again, I apologize for disturbing you, can I ask you if you can write me a code that performs the same function but also prevents writing commas at the beginning, for example like this ,5 or ,36 the code that you wrote performs the function that I wanted perfectly and prevents writing a comma again, but I want I also prevent it from being in the first position. Although it is normal to write it in other programs because, for example ,5 means 0,5 but in Delphi a message appears stating that ,5 is not a decimal number